# Android - Controlling the content of each tab in my tab layout with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I've built an Android app which uses fragments and action bar to create a tab layout. 
The app is made up of:

- MainActivity.java
- PagerAdapter.java
- Tab1Fragment.java
- Tab2Fragment.java
- activity_main.xml
- fragment_tab_1.xml
- fragment_tab_2.xml


  I have this working and I can switch between tabs. My question is how do I control the content of each tab? Obviously I can add my objects to each xml layout but where should I be identifying these objects in my java code? Should I be controlling the content in MainActivity.java or within each separate Fragment.java?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Questions"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ask a Question"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Tab1Fragment.java:**

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);


    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java:**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
                return tab2;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference all of the views within the `Fragment` code. The views within are defined in that specific `Fragment's` xml layout file, so the `Activity` will not be able to reference them easily.

Example:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Get all views here

    return view; //Must return a view
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So should I do this inside onCreateView? or should I put onCreate into my code like I would in a normal activity?

Comment: You will need the `View` returned by the `Inflater` in order to get a reference to the `Views` you want, so it should be done inside `onCreateView`.

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to identify any views. I get an error on findViewById, I think this is because I'm using a Frament class not a FragmentActivity class

Comment: `Fragment` is correct, and I updated my answer to show how to get views.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly understand what you ask but i think you are asking where to code for the specific tabview the answer is in Tab1Fragment and Tab2Fragment.